# XSL pass attributes to child elements if child elements do not already have the same attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes

How can I pass attributes to child elements only if the child elements do not already have the same attribute?

XML:

```
<section>
    <container attribute1="container1" attribute2="container2">
         <p attribute1="test3"/>
         <ol attribute2="test4"/>
    <container>
<section/>
```

Output should look like this:

```
<section>
    <p attribute1="test3" attribute2="test2"/>
    <ol attribute1="container1" attribute2="test4"/>
</section>
```

This is what i tried:

```
<xsl:template match="container">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="passAttributeToChild"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="passAttributeToChildren">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
             <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="name() = name(../@*)"/>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ;) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes declared more than once overwrite each other, so this is easy.

```
<xsl:template match="container/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../@*" /> <!-- take default from parent -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />    <!-- overwrite if applicable -->
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes you want *all* parent attributes, as your sample seems to indicate. Of course you can decide which attributes you want to inherit:

```
    <xsl:copy-of select="../@attribute1 | ../@attribute2" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="@attribute1 | @attribute2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<!-- root and static content - container -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <section>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='section/container/*' />
    </section>
</xsl:template>

<!-- iteration content - child nodes -->
<xsl:template match='*'>
    <xsl:element name='{name()}'>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|parent::*/@*' />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- iteration content - attributes -->
<xsl:template match='@*'>
    <xsl:attribute name='{name()}'><xsl:value-of select='.' /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

On outputting each child node, we iteratively transfer across its attributes and those of the parent.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select='@*|parent::*/@*' />
```

Templates are applied to nodes in the order they appear in the XML. So the parent (`container`) node appears before the child nodes (of course), so it's the parent's attributes that are handled first by the attributes template.

This is handy because it means the template will always show preference to the child nodes' own attributes if they already exist, because they are handled last and thus take precedence over any attributes with the same name from the parent. Thus, the parent cannot overrule them.

**Working demo** at [this XMLPlayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/FtkQPa).

Comment: Should work as well, but Tomalak's solution was easier to apply to my stylesheet. Thank you very much anyway.